# Running old Java applets from book "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java"

Tags: java

I am trying to run the Java applets that accompany the book "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java" by Robert Lafore.

They can be found on this site

https://cs.brynmawr.edu/Courses/cs206/spring2004/lafore.html

The applets do not work for some reason. I've tried adding the different url's for the different applets to my exception site list under Java's security configuration, but that didn't help.

Anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: one of the most likely issues is that most browsers no longer support applets. stop learning them. they are (very) out of date. the few browsers that still allow them, will drop support soon enough

Comment: Java has deprecated and [finally removed applets](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html). If you really wanted it to work, you need to install an old version of java (maybe 8, where applets are still deprecated) and install a browser that still supports applet tags.

Comment: @SBylemans No code involved here.

Comment: @KaNa0011 Ah, I see then. Thanks

Comment: @BorisGrunwald you are aware that applets are not magical things, but actually pieces of (compiled/running/...) code? if there is no code involved here, this question shouldn't have been posted on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said, you should rather avoid applet based samples. However, if you still need them, take a look here:

https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7u75/ri/jdk_ri-7u75-b13-linux-x64-18_dec_2014.tar.gz

You will find `appletviewer` there. Appletviewer allows you to run applets. It might be you will have to play with `JAVA_HOME` environment in order to make sure you use this particular version of Java.